# cloud9でのコンテキストファイルにおけるディレクトリがわかりません。

Tags: java, tomcat, jsp

#### 前提・実現したいこと

cloud9でコンテキストファイルを設定したいです。

【表示したいファイル】
**learning_groovegear/Java/programing_base1/programing_base1_1.jsp**

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

【ブラウザで表示されています】

```
HTTPステータス 404 - /hellojsp/programing_base1_1.jsp
```

#### 該当のソースコード

【ディレクトリ】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【コンテキストファイル(**learning_groovegear/Java/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/conf/Catalina/programing_base1.xml**)】

```
<Context path="/hellojsp" docBase="~/workspace/Java/programing_base1"/>
<script/>
</Context>
```

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

ローカルホストは起動しています。
あらゆるURLを試したので、ファイルが表示されないのは、
コンテキストファイルのdocBaseが正しく設定されていないためだと思われます。

cloud9のディレクトリ構造がよくわからず躓いてしまいました。
ネットに情報も落ちていなく困っています。

もし、わかる方がいらっしゃれば、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

マルチポスト
https://teratail.com/questions/55650?modal=q-comp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分がやった手順を書いたほうが早いと思うので、そうします。

フォルダ構造:

```
~/workspace (左UIではワークスペースの名前になる)
|-apache-tomcat-8.5.8
| |-bin
| |-config
| | |-Catalina
| | | |-localhost
| | |   |-helloZZZ.xml <- コンテキストファイル
| | |-localhostフォルダ以外いろいろ
| |-lib,logsなど動かすだけには関係無いもの
|
|-helloAAA <- コンテキストで指定したフォルダ
  |-index.html
  |-index.jsp
```

1. まずCloud9のJavaはJava7なのでTomcat9のサポート対象ではありません。Tomcat8を落として、解凍。
2. `$JAVA_HOME`ならびに`$CATALINA_HOME`環境変数を指定（`$JAVA_HOME`のフォルダは今後変わるかもしれないです。その際は`/bin/java`からリンクを辿って見つけてください。`$CATALINA_HOME`は解凍したTomcatフォルダ。）

   ```
   $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
   $ export CATALINA_HOME=~/workspace/apache-tomcat-8.5.8
   ```
3. この段階でTomcatは動くはずなので、起動させる。

   ```
   $ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
   ```
4. 上の「Preview」を押すか、タブで`https://<ワークスペース名>-<ユーザー名>.c9users.io/`にアクセスでTomcatのそれっぽいページが表示されるはず。
   [image: Tomcat test]
5. コンテキストを書き、`~/workspace/tomcat/config/Catalina/localhost/`内に置く。`docBase=`はなぜか`~/workspace`ではダメなので絶対パスを。
   `helloZZZ.xml`の中身(ファイル名と`path=`は同じに。):

   ```
   <Context path="/helloZZZ" docBase="/home/ubuntu/workspace/helloAAA"/>
   ```
6. 適当にhtmlやjspファイルを作って`docBase=`で指定したフォルダに入れる。`https://<ワークスペース名>-<ユーザー名>.c9users.io/helloZZZ`のような感じでアクセスできるはずです。
   jspの例:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Hello World!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>

   <%
   out.println(new java.util.Date());
   %>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

[image: hello.jsp]

7. Tomcatを止める(放置でも多分2時間くらいでCloud9が強制的に止めたと思います)。

   ```
   $ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop
   ```